# Ambiguous action methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a web page www.example.com which points to a HomeController index. When I run the website I get the HomeView.

Now the requirement is when I type www.example.com/Japan I need to run a different view.

What I did:

```
 public ActionResult Index(string country)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "my country=" + country;

        return View();
    }
```

But it gives me an error:

> The current request for action 'Index' on controller type 'HomeController' 
>        is ambiguous between the following action methods:
>
> System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index() on type MvcApplication_2.Controllers.HomeController
>        System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Index(System.String) on type   MvcApplication_2.Controllers.HomeController

What should I be doing to achieve this one?

I do not want to use http://example.com/country/japan.

I want to use http://example.com/japan.

my code:
RouteConfig.cs

```
 namespace MvcApplication_2
 {
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "ByCountry",
        url: "{country}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "IndexByCountry" }
    );


    }
}
```

}

Homecontroller.cs

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

        return View();
    }


    [ActionName("IndexByCountry")]
    public ActionResult Index(string country)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Japan man.";

        return View("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Contact()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your route definitions?

Comment: just the default route definitions. I have not added any one.

Comment: You need to register the `ByCountry` route *before* the `Default` route.  Switch up that order so the default route is last.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have the same HTTP verb for the same action name.  In other words, having `HttpGet` for the same action name, even an overload, isn't possible.

You have three options:

Change one or your action methods to a different HTTP action verb...

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //..
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string country)
{
    //..
}
```

Or, change the name of your action method...

```
public ActionResult CountryIndex(string country)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "my country=" + country;

    return View();
}
```

Or, you can change the action name from the overloaded method...

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //..
}

[ActionName("IndexByCountryName")]
public ActionResult Index(string country)
{
    //..
}
```

## Working example

*This uses the last option, keeping the method name overloaded but specify the `ActionNameAttribute` for the overload*

**Actions**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "no country selected!";

        return View();
    }

    [ActionName("IndexByCountry")]
    public ActionResult Index(string country)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = string.Format("County selected :: {0}", country);

        // the below ActionResult reuses the Index view but 
        // here you could have a separate view for the country 
        // selection if you like
        //
        return View("Index");
    }
```

**Routes**

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ByCountry",
            url: "{country}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "IndexByCountry" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: If i change the name of the actionmethod to countryIndex how will the URL be accessed for Japan.

Comment: I changed as per your suggestion one with httpget and other with httppost, but it didnot work. when i typed in http://example.com/japan i got The resource cannot be found.

Comment: @Venkat That's because your request is still a GET by that method.  If/when you change the action name then you'll have to have another route for that.

Comment: Thomas Stringer. Can u assist how the router should be written in this case? I have not written any. Just the default one.

Comment: @Venkat Take a look at my edit, that's a working example.  I hope that helps!

Comment: @Venkat I'm not sure what to tell you here, the "working example" here is indeed working in my environment.  There are no ambiguous actions between those two in my example.  Ensure that you don't have any other pairs of ambiguous actions in your controller.

Comment: @Venkat You need to register the `ByCountry` route *before* your `Default` route.  The order does matter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use AttributeRouting.

```
[Route("Home/Index/{country}")
public ActionResult Index(string country)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "my country=" + country;

    switch(country)
    {
        case "Country1":
             return View("ViewName")
    }

    // To do
}
```